# Not a managed type during app context initialization

Tags: spring, hibernate, generics, spring-data-jpa

I cannot figure out why entity objects cannot be managed by DAO classes.

I have the following PersistenceConfig file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.wx.rm")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.wx.rm"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource restDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
                setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",  env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
                setProperty("hibernate.format_sql",  env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers"));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Interface IFooAdvertDao:

```
@Repository("fooAdvertDao")
public interface IFooAdvertDao extends GenericDao<FooAdvert, String> {
}
```

Interface IBarAdvertDao:

```
@Repository("barAdvertDao")
public interface IBarAdvertDao  extends GenericDao<BarAdvert, Integer> {
}
```

Base entity BaseAdvert class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseAdvert implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "link")
    private String link;

    @Column(name = "rooms")
    private BigDecimal rooms;
    public BaseAdvert() {
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public BigDecimal getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public void setRooms(BigDecimal rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }
}
```

Entity FooAdvert class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_adverts")
@DynamicUpdate
public class FooAdvert extends BaseAdvert implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private Integer type;

    public FooAdvert() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Entity BarAdvert class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bar_adverts")
@DynamicUpdate
public class BarAdvert extends BaseAdvert implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer status;

    public BarAdvert() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

That`s my GenericDao class:

```
@Repository
public interface GenericDao<T extends Serializable, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
}
```

Generic service class:

```
public interface GenericService <T extends Serializable, ID extends Serializable> {

    T findOne(final ID id);

    Page<T> findAll(final Pageable pageable);

    long count();

}
```

Generic service implementation class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class GenericServiceImpl <T extends Serializable, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericService<T, ID> {

    @Autowired
    private GenericDao<T, ID> genericDao;

    public GenericServiceImpl() {
    }

    public GenericServiceImpl(GenericDao<T, ID> genericDao) {
        this.genericDao = genericDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public T findOne(ID id) {
        return genericDao.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return genericDao.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public long count() {
        return genericDao.count();
    }
}
```

FooAdvertService:

```
@Service
public class FooAdvertService extends GenericServiceImpl<FooAdvert, String> {

    @Autowired
    private IFooAdvertDao fooAdvertDao;

}
```

FooAdvertController class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FooAdvertController {

    @Autowired
    private FooAdvertService fooAdvertService;

    @GetMapping("count")
    public ResponseEntity getAdvertsCount() {
        Long advertsCount = fooAdvertService.count();
        return new ResponseEntity(advertsCount, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Error message when I try to run my app:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fooAdvertController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fooAdvertService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fooAdvertService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'genericDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooAdvertDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.wixanz.rm.ads.domain.FooAdvert
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fooAdvertService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'genericDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooAdvertDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.wixanz.rm.ads.domain.FooAdvert
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooAdvertDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.wixanz.rm.ads.domain.FooAdvert
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.wixanz.rm.ads.domain.FooAdvert
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

Comment: did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

try to autowire the IFooAdvertDao by name

```
@Service
public class FooAdvertService extends GenericServiceImpl<FooAdvert, String> 
{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fooAdvertDao")
    private IFooAdvertDao fooAdvertDao;

}
```